# Can Flutter make Application in kiosk mode?

Tags: flutter, mobile, kiosk-mode

Can Flutter make Application in kiosk mode? if yes How I can do this? is there any docs or tutorials can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be achieved by building an application for web browser and then running it in fullscreen mode on Chrome by a CLI command.

I've successfully used this approach to deliver app in kiosk mode for machines running Linux (but I'm pretty sure it will be ok on Win too).

CORS restrictions can be switched off by a special flag when you run Chrome from CLI. So the only thing that can be a limitation in this case - is that your app does not have a direct access to the file system on the machine.

Comment: I was wondering the same question, but concluded that in some cases it would not be your #1 choice. I use LAMP stack with WordPress. That gives you user control and DB framework right out of the box, plus you can dance on your head using PHP in backend - files, serial ports, shell, custom protocols etc, plus lots of JS widgets that do not exist in other frameworks. I've interfaced with PLC's and equipment using this approach and have done a ton of projects, including surveillance systems. HTML5 is hard to beat